# Vue.js - I have dynamic buttons and I want that the color changes if I clicked one button

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have created buttons dynamically with v-for and now I want that the button which is clicked changes the colour and the other have all the same colour.

```js
<template>
  <div id="exam-screen" class="exam jumbotron">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-md-6" v-bind:key="exam.id" v-for="exam in getExam">
        <button
          class="exam exam-btn btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block"
          v-bind:id="
            'exam-' + exam.id + '-' + exam.season + '-' + exam.year + '-btn'
          "
        >
          <span>{{ exam['season_de'] }} {{ exam.year }} </span>
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-md-8"></p>
      <BaseButton>{{ startButton }}</BaseButton>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I know that I need a v-on:click directive, but I don't know how I change the color...

I already managed that in JavaScript, but I don't know how it works in Vue.js...

```js
How I do it in JavaScript:

function selectAnswer(id) {
    $(id).addClass("btn-primary");
    $(id).removeClass("btn-secondary");
}

function deselectAnswer(id) {
    $(id).addClass("btn-secondary");
    $(id).removeClass("btn-primary");
}
```

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: Check this Vue documentation
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: I've already looked at this ... but somehow I can't figure it out ... I also watched Videos of Vue Mastery...but I don't know why I don't understand it now...

Comment: Sry, but what do you mean with a demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add & remove a class from the buttons using [`@click`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) & [`:class`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {
    items: [{text: 'This is Button 1'},{text: 'This is Button 1'},{text: 'This is Button 3'}]
  },
  methods: {
    toggleClass(index) {
      this.items.forEach(item => item.active=false);
      let item = this.items[index];
      item.active = !item.active;
      this.$set(this.items, index, item);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="myApp">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <button 
      :class="{ 'btn-primary': item.active, 'btn-secondary': !item.active}" 
      @click="toggleClass(index)" 
      class="btn btn-md btn-block m-3">
      <span>{{ item.text }} </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that `@click` is just a shorthand for `v-on:click` and `:class` is just a shorthand for `v-bind:class`. Also, we need to remove `btn-secondary` class that we set initially to the buttons otherwise `btn-primary` does not take effect on the button on click.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it, but the problem is now that more than one button can be selected...and I want that only one button can be selected and the others are then unselected...how does this work?

Comment: And what does this.$set(...) ? Can you explain?

Comment: " I want that only one button can be selected and the others are then unselected" - I have added this logic.

Comment: "And what does this.$set" - You can learn more about this in details here [Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. :) 
But `this.items.forEach((item, idx) => item.active=false);` works without idx....is that a typo? Or for what stands idx?

Comment: You can ignore that, just was testing something.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I installed it again in another component, but somehow it doesn't work .... I get the following error message in the console: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined"

Can you help me again?

Comment: Sorry, but I will be offline soon. Could you please create a separate question for this issue and also add a demo there, just like I did and then post the question link here. I will try to look at it tomorrow and provide a solution, if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006044/vue-js-click-only-one-button-per-group-for-dynamic-button-generation